# How to access settings.xml in Azure Service Fabric stateful/stateless service?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

How can I access and read parameters definied in **PackageRoot/Settings/Settings.xml** file from my stateful/stateless service code?
For example I have a section DocumentDbConfig with Parameter EndpointUrl:

```
<Section Name="DocumentDbConfig">
  <Parameter Name="EndpointUrl" Value="{url}"/>
</Section>
```

And I would like to read it in my code:

```
public async Task<ServiceActionResult<Result>> GetResult()
{
    _client = new Client({{ EndpointUrl }});  //HOW TO GET ENDPOINT URL FROM SETTINGS?
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do you set and access run-time configuration parameters per environment for service fabric?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33928204/where-do-you-set-and-access-run-time-configuration-parameters-per-environment-fo)

Answer (score 0):

As long as your code has access to the `ServiceContext` you can access all of the configuration packages that were deployed with your service. For example:

```cs
serviceContext.CodePackageActivationContext.GetConfigurationPackageObject("Config")
```

where `"Config"` is the name of the configuration package. From there, you can access all of the sections and keys/values within each section. Be sure to refer to the [ConfigurationPackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.configurationpackage?view=azure-dotnet) documentation as a guide on how to access this data, as well as how to listen to events that fire when the configuration package changes.