# What is the equivalent of RoleEnvironment in Service Fabric?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm migrating a Cloud Service application to a Service Fabric application.
I'm looking for a ServiceEnvironment equivalent to RoleEnvironment in order to get the service name from the environment variables.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-environment-variables-reference

Comment: These are "normal" environment variables, right? Have you tried Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable() ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: I'm looking for a more elegant way to use it instead of environment variable. Of course, I can create a wrapper object.

Comment: Are you looking for a way of managing your services configuration not using environment variables or a different way of reading environment variables? If it's the first, then use Settings.xml https://stackoverflow.com/q/36640752/352826, if it's the latter https://stackoverflow.com/q/33928204/352826

Comment: As I wrote, I looking for a wrapper object in the framework to read the environment variables of the fabric service like Fabric_ServiceName, Fabric_ServicePackageName. I always can create such a wrapper object. However, I'm looking for an object in the framework.

Comment: In the constructor of your microservice, you get an instance of ServiceContext (the concrete class depends on the type of microservice). This Context https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.servicecontext?view=azure-dotnet contains a lot of information, with things like ServiceName, ServiceType, information about the Node, information about the Application, etc.

Comment: Thanks @FrancescCastells for your answer!