# Where & how does one instantiate ServiceInitializationParameters in an Azure Service Fabric service?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

Trying to use custom application configuration in my service. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33928204/where-do-you-set-and-access-run-time-configuration-parameters-per-environment-fo/33944415#33944415) gives part of the answer, but it doesn't explain how & where you initialize the **ServiceInitializationParameters** object, which is required to get it working. The object does not seem to have a constructor. [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.fabric.statelessserviceinitializationparameters.aspx) from Microsoft is sketchy and the [provided sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-web-reference-app) on GitHub does not seem to use any custom app config.

Answer (score 3):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33928204/where-do-you-set-and-access-run-time-configuration-parameters-per-environment-fo/33944415#33944415) is based on the preview SDK. In the [release version](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2016/03/31/announcing-service-fabric-ga-on-azure-public-preview-of-standalone-clusters-on-windows-server-and-limited-preview-on-linux/) (2.0+) of the SDK, ServiceInitializationParameters was replaced with [ServiceContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.fabric.servicecontext.aspx) and its derived [stateless](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.fabric.statelessservicecontext.aspx) and [stateful](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.fabric.statefulservicecontext.aspx) versions. Check out the [release notes](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=784910&clcid=0x409) for a comprehensive list of all the changes from preview to release.

Everything else in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33928204/where-do-you-set-and-access-run-time-configuration-parameters-per-environment-fo/33944415#33944415) is still accurate, but you access the config stuff like this now:

```
 var configurationPackage = this.Context.CodePackageActivationContext.GetConfigurationPackageObject("Config");

 var connectionStringParameter = configurationPackage.Settings.Sections["UserDatabase"].Parameters["UserDatabaseConnectionString"];
```

Comment: this update should be reflected on the official doco page https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cloud-services-migration-worker-role-stateless-service/