# Accessing application parameters directly from service

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

Is it possible to access parameters defined in the ApplicationManifest.xml directly from your SF services?

I know you can define parameters on service level and provide overrides (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33928204/where-do-you-set-and-access-run-time-configuration-parameters-per-environment-fo)) but it is very cumbersome. If you have several services accessing same parameter (e.g. connection string) then it would be much easier to have it defined in a single place, like app manifest.

Comment: The whole idea of microservices is to be independent. So it is natural to have the same connection string in several places for each service.

Comment: Using same config params for commons things doesn't break their independence but would ease the maintenance. I'm configuring elastic search listeners to collect logs as advised in tutorials and I need to implement 4 overrides per each service - a lot of work for such a simple goal...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, but not easy.

1. Get the manifest xml:

> ```
> var fc = new FabricClient();         
> var application = (await fc.QueryManager.GetApplicationListAsync(new Uri (Context.CodePackageActivationContext.ApplicationName))).Single();         
> var applicationManifest = await fc.ApplicationManager.GetApplicationManifestAsync(application.ApplicationTypeName,
>  application.ApplicationTypeVersion);
> ```

2. Use that xml to deserialize an object based on the XSD schema. C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\schemas\ServiceFabricServiceModel.xsd (ApplicationManifestType)

(sorry about the formatting)

Comment: But this mechanism would not use environment-specific overrides from the ApplicationParameters folder, right?

Comment: application.ApplicationParameters
has those