# How to access applicationtypename specified in applicationmanifest in c#code

Tags: c#, .net, azure, service, azure-service-fabric

How do I access ApplicationTypeName specified in the applicationmanifest in c#code at runtime

I tried `var applicationTypeName = FabricRuntime.GetActivationContext().ApplicationTypeName; var applicationName = FabricRuntime.GetActivationContext().ApplicationName; if (tracer != null) { tracer.Log($"applicationTypeName:{applicationTypeName}"); tracer.Log($"applicationName:{applicationName}"); }` But this is giving me service nametype not application nametype.

`<ApplicationManifest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ApplicationTypeName="xyz" ApplicationTypeVersion="1.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">`

In this example, I want xyz to be fetched.

Answer (score 0):

- In Service Fabric services, the `ApplicationTypeName` specified in the application manifest is not directly accessible from within the service code.

We can dynamically retrieve and inspect the application manifest at runtime.

```cs
using System.Fabric;

class YourService : StatelessService
{
    public YourService(StatelessServiceContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
        try
        {
            var activationContext = context.CodePackageActivationContext;

            if (activationContext != null)
            {
                var applicationTypeName = activationContext.ApplicationTypeName;
                ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(this, $"ApplicationTypeName: {applicationTypeName}");      
            }
            else
            {
                // Log an error or handle the null activationContext case
                ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(this, "Error: Activation context is null.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log an error or handle the exception
            ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(this, $"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

- Using `context.CodePackageActivationContext` directly to access the activation context within the `StatelessService`.

Here check this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39033443/20238030), he used `FabricClient` to query for the application manifest and then deserialize it into an object based on the XSD schema. By this he is able to access properties of that object, such as `ApplicationTypeName`.

**ServiceManifest.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceManifest ...>
  <ServiceTypes>
    <StatelessServiceType ...>
      <!-- Other configuration settings -->
      <ConfigurationOverrides>
        <ConfigOverrides Name="Config">
          <Settings>
            <Section Name="ApplicationInfo">
              <Parameter Name="ApplicationTypeName" Value="xyz" />
            </Section>
          </Settings>
        </ConfigOverrides>
      </ConfigurationOverrides>
    </StatelessServiceType>
  </ServiceTypes>
  <!-- ... -->
</ServiceManifest>
```