# Custome developer environment variables for local service fabric clusters?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

When debugging service fabric applications locally it would be nice if developers could have some custom private configuration settings. The application parameters and publish profiles allow per environment configuration but not per developer configuration (unless I've missed something).

I need a way to have service fabric applications running in local clusters to get local configuration values. So each engineer can have their applications running locally point to a private database, IoT Hub, external web service instance and other private resources. Environment variables would work as overrides but the local cluster doesn't pick them up from the host machine.

Is there some way to provide this type of local configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are mapped to something else with SF dev cluster, just like `%temp%` folder is. Since that would be a static info, perhaps it should come from static configuration that is not checked into repository.

There's [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41565653/59563) with an answer you were looking for, but it still requires to update SF manifest file.

Update: environment variables scoped to User won't be available. System scoped environment variables will be accessible. VS needs to be restarted to see values of system scoped env variables if those are updated.