# How to call a WCF service from Service fabric actor

Tags: wcf, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-actor, service-fabric-on-premises

I have a service fabric actor which does something and at the end, it calls another WCF service in an async way. The real question is how do I pass the endpoint information as well as binding information to the actor?

Comment: You can use the settings model. Did you see this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/33944415/5946937

Comment: Is the WCF service is also hosted in same service fabric cluster as well? If so, then you can query to fabric\NamingService for endpoint, binding and protocol.